# Check if a list has specific number of whole numbers

Tags: python

So I tried to do something like `list.is_integer()` but I don't think it's working.

Is there any method to determine if a `list` has for example 2 whole numbers in it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: can you share an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the number, simply use the `in` operator:

```
1 in [1, 2, 3]
# True
```

if you want to check the *whole* list consisting of integers, you'll need to use something different, for example:

```py
all(isinstance(item, int) for item in [1, 2, 3])
# True
```

[`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) helps evaluating all of the values of an iterable and the condition for all items of a list being of `int` type can be checked by [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) function.

For specific *count* of the occurrences, simply switch `all()` to [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) which will add all of the truthy values that fulfill the condition:

```py
sum(isinstance(item, int) for item in [1, 2, "3"])
# 2
```